# How to collectionQuery from a subcollection with index configuration in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to get my **events** from my Firestore Database with the `collectionGroup` query, as I think this is the function that fits my use case best.
In the following method below, I want to get all **events** from each **association**.

```js
  getEventsWithCollectionGroupQuery(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.afs
      .collectionGroup<Event>(EVENTS_COLLECTION, (ref) => ref.where('published', '==', true))
      .get()
      .pipe(
       // Error gets thrown here
        map((snapshot) => {
          return snapshot.docs.map((eventDoc) => {
            const associationId = eventDoc.ref.parent.parent?.id;
            return {
              ...eventDoc.data(),
              id: eventDoc.id,
              association: associationId,
            };
          });
        })
      );
  }
```

Just for clarification:

- I understand that the `collectionGroup` query should return all collections that are named like the collectionID provided in it.
- I have got 2 collections named `events`, once as a top-level collection and once as a subcollection under `associations/{association=**}/events`.

Seems pretty alright to me, but sadly it isn't. When trying to run the method in my front end and subscribing to it in the HTML I get the following error.

`Firestore error: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I can't really understand, why I get the **Missing or insufficient permissions** error, since I've allowed access to both of the collections with `allow read: if true`.

-> Does anyone notice any other possible problem with it or is it really because of the firestore rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that the collectionGroup query should return all collections that are named like the collectionID provided in it.

Yes, that is entirely correct. It doesn't matter if there are top-level collections or sub-collections, you should be able to get the results.

> I have got 2 collections named events, once as a top-level collection and once as a subcollection under associations/{association=**}/events.

Yes, that would definitely work.

You're getting the following error:

> Firestore error: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Because the Firebase servers reject the read operation.

> Does anyone notice any other possible problem with it or is it really because of the Firestore rules?

Yes, it's because of the Firestore rules. For testing purposes, I recommend you use one of the following options:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 11, 13);
    }
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to read the data until 2023-11-13. However, when your app gets in production, remember to write the [proper rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: Hey Daniel. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hey Alex. It worked for me, thanks. I will mark your answer.